# Firebase Cloud messaging receiving percentage low

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We use an app that we send pushmessages too. We get complains about users not getting the message even though they have everything setup (gave permission, etc).

Now when I look in the Firebase Cloud Messaging Report I see that we've send 56K push notifications last 3 months, but 13K are received. Does this imply that 43K never reached the phone? If so, why is this so high?